# Multi_match elasticsearch on all fields with boost to specific fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am using Elastic 6.1+
I have created an index and added some values to it, the index mapping is text and numbers.

I want to create a multi_match on all of the fields in the index, query a text or a number and get the results back.
Also i would like to define that the score of field1 on the index is boosted

For some reason once i add the fields array it only search on that fields (added it in order to be able to define which field i want to boost and how much) and if i add to the fields array the "*" as field it return an error.

```
GET MyIndex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "test1",
      "fields": [
      "field1^3",
      "*"
    ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently adding 
"lenient": true 
to the query solved the problem